# How do I replicate this mongodb regex in query using mongo-scala-driver?

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver, mongodb-scala

I can query mongodb directly using this query `{key: {$in: [/faq/]}}` but how do I replicate this when using [Filters#in](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.1/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/model/Filters$.html#in%5BTItem%5D(fieldName:String,values:TItem*):org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.Bson)?

`in("key", Seq("/faq/"))` doesn't work as it gets passed as a string.

Comment: have you tried regex filter instead in?

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez I am aware of the regex filter but was wondering if it was possible using `in`.